# Performance optimization nested loops

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, optimization, expression

I am implementing a rather complicated code and in one of the critical sections I need to basically consider all the possible strings of numbers following a certain rule. The naive implementation to explain what I do would be such a nested loop implementation:

```
std::array<int,3> max = { 3, 4, 6};
for(int i = 0; i <= max.at(0); ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j <= max.at(1); ++j){
       for(int k = 0; k <= max.at(2); ++k){  
           DoSomething(i, j, k);
       }
     }
 }
```

Obviously I actually need more nested for and the "max" rule is more complicated but the idea is clear I think.
I implemented this idea using a recursive function approach:

```
std::array<int,3> max = { 3, 4, 6};
std::array<int,3> index = {0, 0, 0};
int total_depth = 3;
recursive_nested_for(0, index, max, total_depth);
```

where

```
void recursive_nested_for(int depth, std::array<int,3>& index,
                     std::array<int,3>& max, int total_depth)
{
    if(depth != total_depth){
        for(int i = 0; i <= max.at(depth); ++i){
            index.at(depth) = i;
            recursive_nested_for(depth+1, index, max, total_depth);
        }
    }
    else
        DoSomething(index);  
}
```

In order to save as much as possible I declare all the variable I use global in the actual code.

Since this part of the code takes really long is it possible to do anything to speed it up?
I would also be open to write 24 nested for if necessary to avoid the overhead at least!
I thought that maybe an approach like expressions templates to actually generate at compile time these nested for could be more elegant. But is it possible?
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks to all.

Comment: Three nested loops is going to result in a time complexity of O(N^3). Are you sure your algorithm is as optimal as it can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `recursive_nested_for()` is a nice idea. It's a bit inflexible as it is currently written. However, you could use `std::vector<int>` for the array dimensions and indices, or make it a template to handle any size `std::array<>`. The compiler might be able to inline all recursive calls if it knows how deep the recursion is, and then it will probably be just as efficient as the three nested for-loops.

Another option is to use a single for loop for incrementing the indices that need incrementing:

```
void nested_for(std::array<int,3>& index, std::array<int,3>& max)
{
    while (index.at(2) < max.at(2)) {
      DoSomething(index);

      // Increment indices
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
          if (++index.at(i) >= max.at(i))
             index.at(i) = 0;
          else
             break;
      }
   }
}
```

However, you can also consider creating a linear sequence that visits all possible combinations of the iterators `i`, `j`, `k` and so on. For example, with array dimensions `{3, 4, 6}`, there are 3 * 4 * 6 = 72 possible combinations. So you can have a single counter going from 0 to 72, and then "split" that counter into the three iterator values you need, like so:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 72; c++) {
    int k = c % 6;
    int j = (c / 6) % 4;
    int i = c / 6 / 4;
    DoSomething(i, j, k);
}
```

You can generalize this to as many dimensions as you want. Of course, the more dimensions you have, the higher the cost of splitting the linear iterator. But if your array dimensions are powers of two, it might be very cheap to do so. Also, it might be that you don't need to split it at all; for example if you are calculating the sum of all elements of a multidimensional array, you don't care about the actual indices `i`, `j`, `k` and so on, you just want to visit all elements once. If the array is layed out linearly in memory, then you just need a linear iterator.

Of course, if you have 24 nested for loops, you'll notice that the product of all the dimension's sizes will become a very large number. If it doesn't fit in a 32 bit integer, your code is going to be very slow. If it doesn't fit into a 64 bit integer anymore, it will never finish.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I can work on it! Well this code is supposed to run for days if not weeks before it gives me the few numbers I need, so I am aware I am fighting wind mills basically but any improvement maybe worthy!